# TF-IDF Matrix In Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk

My code to calculate `TF-IDF` for a corpus goes like this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

train_set = "i have a ball", "he is good", "she played well" 
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)

train_array = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).toarray()
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(train_array)
```

The output I receive is:

```
['ball', 'good', 'have', 'he', 'is', 'played', 'she', 'well']

[[0.70710678, 0., 0.70710678, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0.57735027, 0., 0.57735027, 0.57735027, 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.57735027, 0.57735027, 0.57735027]]
```

The question is how can I calculate `TF-IDF` of the sentence: `"she is good"`? The corpus is the `train_set` in the above code.

Answer (score 4):

You simply apply your `TF-IDF` vectorizer on new data with `.transform` method:

```
In [16]: test = ["she is good"]

In [17]: test_array = vectorizer.transform(test)

In [18]: test_array.A
Out[18]: array([[0., 0.57735027, 0., 0., 0.57735027, 0., 0.57735027, 0.]])

In [19]: vectorizer.get_feature_names()
Out[19]: ['ball', 'good', 'have', 'he', 'is', 'played', 'she', 'well']
```